# Search for the presence of a string in multiple arrays of a document in mongo db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I wand to make a query in which I would provide a _id and country name now as a result I want to find the true or false value if the given country is present in these three arrays or not. If present then true instead false. For example I have ***country:France*** and **_id:5e4d18bd10e5482eb623c6e4** then result will be-

country_array_1:true,
country_array_2:true,
country_array_3:false

I want a mongo db query for this type of input and output I can be aggregate or findOne but I want my answer

```
 0  _id:5e4d18bd10e5482eb623c6e4
       country_array_1:['France','Italy','China'],
       country_array_2:['Finland','England','France']
       country_array_3:['USA','turkey','India']

 1  _id:5e4345bd10e5482eb62E4X11f
       country_array_1:['Srilanka','Malaysia','Pakistan'],
       country_array_2:['Egypt','Austria','Netherland']
       country_array_3:['Mexico','turkey','India']
```

I want to make a query in which I would give input as

```
[Input]
 _id:5e4d18bd10e5482eb623c6e4,
 country:'France'

[Output]
 country_array_1:true,
 country_array_2:true,
 country_array_3:false
```

Comment: look into mongo aggregation pipeline, you can definitely achieve this.

Comment: I have looked and tried but I am not getting accurate answer and yes you are correct the answer will be achieved through aggregation but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregation pipeline

```
db.test.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: ObjectId("5e4d18bd10e5482eb623c6e4") } },
  {
    $project: {
      country_array_1: {
        $in: ["France", "$country_array_1"]
      },
      country_array_2: {
        $in: ["France", "$country_array_2"]
      },
      country_array_3: {
        $in: ["France", "$country_array_3"]
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Output:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4d18bd10e5482eb623c6e4"),
    "country_array_1" : false,
    "country_array_2" : true,
    "country_array_3" : false
}
```

Comment: will it return boolean result?

Comment: yeah give it a try

Comment: MongoError: $in requires an array as a second argument, found: missing
I got this error

Comment: Thanks pavan, I tried it for some times and after some mistakes it worked.Thank you for help